# Cannot do a CASE WHEN query using getContentResolver().query()

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contacts

Im trying to perform the following query on the device's contacts:

```
final String[] PROJECTION = {
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
        String.format("CASE WHEN " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " LIKE '%%%s%%' THEN 'full' END name_match", mFirstName)
};

String SELECTION = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " LIKE ?";

String[] selectionArgs = {mFirstName};

String ORDER_BY = "name_match ASC";

Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, SELECTION, selectionArgs, ORDER_BY);
```

But i get the following exception:

> ```
>                                              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column CASE WHEN display_name LIKE '%john%' THEN 'full' END name_match
>                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.computeProjection(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:632)
>                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.buildQuery(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:447)
>                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:387)
>                                                  at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.query(ContactsProvider2.java:7812)
>                                                  at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.queryLocal(ContactsProvider2.java:7550)
>                                                  at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.query(ContactsProvider2.java:6037)
>                                                  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:238)
>                                                  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
>                                                  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
> ```

What is wrong here ? Is it possible to perform a CASE WHEN queries on a content provider ? on contacts table ? If not, is there any alternative to do such a query ?

Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to do? why not check the `LIKE %?%` in the selection instead? it doesn't makes sense to put it in the projection...

Comment: I've shortened the code to concentrate on the issue. I have a few other CASE WHEN conditions which i removed. what im trying to do is have another column which will contain the name match result - full match/first name match/last name match.

Comment: I looked at the AOSP code a bit an there's a class variable on SQLiteQueryBuilder which is called mStrict. When set to true it doesnt allow using anything else in the SELECT part besides actual table columns. And of course the contacts provider is setting it to true. i dont get it...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing what you want in the ContentProvider (which seems impossible), you can pretty easily do it in code:

```
final String[] projection = { ... };
String selection = Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " LIKE %?%";
String[] selectionArgs = { mFirstName };
Cursor cursor = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
List<String> fullMatch = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> partialMatch = new ArrayList<>();
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
   String name = cursor.getString(3); // exact number depends on your projection
   if (mFirstName.equalsIgnoreCase(name) {
      fullMatch.add(name);
   } else {
      partialMatch.add(name);
   }
}
cursor.close();
List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<>();
allMatches.addAll(fullMatch);
allMatches.addAll(partialMatch);
```